# Proving or disproving a claim about limits

Tags: limits, proof-writing, examples-counterexamples

[image]

I was asked to prove or disprove this claim. I've tried to find a counter example but I've got a feeling now that the statement is correct.
My guess is they want us to prove it using the squeeze rule, but how would I approach this?
I can see straight away that $0 < f(x) \le1$, but how does that help me? should I perhaps try to use the contrapositive or proof by contradiction?

Comment: Hi. What bout $$f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2}\\D_f=\mathbb{R}-\{0\}$$

Comment: Hi thanks for the response! I'm not asked to find an f(x) that satisfys this, I am asked to prove a statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints

Does $f(x)$ have to be a positive function?

Can $f(x)$ be positive for $x < 0$?

Can $f(x)$ have two specifications, one for positive $x$ and one for negative $x$?

Does $g(x)$ have to be a positive function?

Can you define a function $f(x)$ such that $xf(x)$ goes towards $-\infty$ as $x$ approaches $0$ from above?

Comment: Hi thanks for the response! I'm only a few weeks into my calculus course so forgive me for not quiet getting the hint. But what does it mean when x approaches from above?

Comment: @MathCurious For example, when $x$ takes on the values $(1/10), (1/100), (1/1000), ...$  That is, when $x$ becomes a smaller and smaller number, but always remains a positive number.